# Shell script to recursively browse a directory and replace a string

Tags: regex, scripting

I need to recursively search directories and replace a string (say http://development:port/URI) with another (say http://production:port/URI) in all the files where ever it's found. Can anyone help?

It would be much better if that script can print out the files that it modified and takes the search/replace patterns as input parameters.

Regards.

Comment: What platform?  What languages will you accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l development | xargs perl -i.bak -p -e 's(http://development)(http://production)g'
```

Another approach with slightly more feedback:

```
find . -type f | while read file
do
    grep development $file && echo "modifying $file" && perl -i.bak -p -e 's(http://development)(http://prodution)g' $file
done
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the old files will be saved as *.bak, which indirectly satisfies the requirement: "print out the files that it modified".

Answer (score 6):

find . -type f | xargs sed -i s/pattern/replacement/g

Comment: an extra note: you have to escape quotation marks with backslashes in the pattern: ... sed -i s/\"hello\"/hi/g

Comment: results in `invalid command code .`.....

the farthest I got was with this: `find iPhone_Src/ -type f |  xargs sed -i '' -e's/__MyCompanyName__/Samsung Electronics, Inc./g'`....

but even that does the job only half way, giving `sed: iPhone_Src//GUI: in-place editing only works for regular files`.....

Listing: `find iPhone_Src/ -type f | xargs grep -1 -C 0 Copyright 2>/dev/null | grep -v Samsung | head  
Binary file iPhone_Src//image/demo_bt_feedback.png matches  
iPhone_Src//main.m://  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2010. All rights reserved.  
etc. etc.`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would benefit from a layer of indirection.  (But then, who wouldn't?)

I'm thinking that you could have the special string in just one location.  Either reference the configuration settings at runtime, or generate these files with the correct string at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try the above within a working SVN / CVS directory, since it will also patch the .svn/.cvs, which is definitely not what you want. To avoid .svn modifications, for example, use:

```
find . -type f | fgrep -v .svn | xargs sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zsh` so with advanced globing you can use only one command.
E.g.:

```
sed -i 's:pattern:target:g' ./**
```

HTH